# php: number only hash?

Tags: php, hash, md5, numbers, short

In php is there a way to give a unique hash from a string, but that the hash was made up from numbers only?

example:

```
return md5(234); // returns 098f6bcd4621d373cade4e832627b4f6
```

but I need

```
return numhash(234); // returns 00978902923102372190 
(20 numbers only)
```

the problem here is that I want the hashing to be short.

**edit:**
OK let me explain the back story here.
I have a site that has a ID for every registered person, also I need a ID for the person to use and exchange (hence it can't be too long), so far the ID numbering has been 00001, 00002, 00003 etc...

1. this makes some people look more important
2. this reveals application info that I don't want to reveal.

To fix point 1 and 2 I need to "hide" the number while keeping it unique.

### Edit + SOLUTION:

Numeric hash function based on the code by https://stackoverflow.com/a/23679870/175071

```
/**
 * Return a number only hash
 * https://stackoverflow.com/a/23679870/175071
 * @param $str
 * @param null $len
 * @return number
 */
public function numHash($str, $len=null)
{
    $binhash = md5($str, true);
    $numhash = unpack('N2', $binhash);
    $hash = $numhash[1] . $numhash[2];
    if($len && is_int($len)) {
        $hash = substr($hash, 0, $len);
    }
    return $hash;
}

// Usage
numHash(234, 20); // always returns 6814430791721596451
```

Comment: Integer obfuscation as with [`(new Id())->obfuscate($id)`](https://github.com/delight-im/PHP-IDs) should be exactly what you need. If the resulting string doesn’t have to be short and you’re fine with 39 characters as a maximum length, you can also keep MD5 and just convert it to base 10.

Comment: if you don't want to return minus values, you may include some use of  `abs();`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There are some good answers but for me the approaches seem silly.
They first force php to create a Hex number, then convert this back (`hexdec`) in a BigInteger and then cut it down to a number of letters... this is much work!

Instead why not

Read the hash as binary:

```
$binhash = md5('[input value]', true);
```

then using

```
$numhash = unpack('N2', $binhash); //- or 'V2' for little endian
```

to cast this as two `INT`s (`$numhash` is an array of two elements). Now you can reduce the number of bits in the number simply using an `AND` operation. e.g:

```
$result = $numhash[1] & 0x000FFFFF; //- to get numbers between 0 and 1048575
```

**But be warned of collisions!** Reducing the number means increasing the probability of two different [input value] with the same output.

I think that the much better way would be the use of "ID-Crypting" with a Bijectiv function. So no collisions could happen! For the simplest kind just use an [Affine_cipher](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_cipher)

Example with max input value range from 0 to 25:

```
function numcrypt($a)
{
   return ($a * 15) % 26;
}

function unnumcrypt($a)
{
   return ($a * 7) % 26;
}
```

Output:

```
numcrypt(1) : 15
numcrypt(2) : 4
numcrypt(3) : 19

unnumcrypt(15) : 1
unnumcrypt(4)  : 2
unnumcrypt(19) : 3
```

e.g.

```
$id = unnumcrypt($_GET('userid'));

... do something with the ID ...

echo '<a href="do.php?userid='. numcrypt($id) . '"> go </a>';
```

of course this is not secure, but if no one knows the method used for your encryption then there are no security reasons then this way is faster and collision safe.

Comment: I don't understand how to use your second solution to get a number hash, could you elaborate some more?

Comment: it is not a hash but you can use e.g. Blowfish to cover your IDs to a unique "random" number. The user then is not able to calculate "ID+1". In the end you can use this as a proxy methode: internal your APP use "ID: 1,2,3,..." but you provide the crypted numbers to you user. Many big sides do it this way: e.g. the google-cookies are encrypted IDs

Comment: How can you reverse (or pack()) the `unpack('N2', ...)` array?

Answer (score 71):

An MD5 or SHA1 hash in PHP returns a hexadecimal number, so all you need to do is convert bases.  PHP has a function that can do this for you:

```
$bignum = hexdec( md5("test") );
```

or

```
$bignum = hexdec( sha1("test") );
```

[PHP Manual for hexdec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.hexdec.php)

Since you want a limited size number, you could then use modular division to put it in a range you want.

```
$smallnum = $bignum % [put your upper bound here]
```

**EDIT**

As noted by Artefacto in the comments, using this approach will result in a number beyond the maximum size of an Integer in PHP, and the result after modular division will always be 0.  However, taking a substring of the hash that contains the first 16 characters doesn't have this problem.  Revised version for calculating the initial large number:

```
$bignum = hexdec( substr(sha1("test"), 0, 15) );
```

Comment: what if I limit the 'test' variable to a limited set of numbers?
would there be a way of reducing the hash size?

Comment: @YuriKolovsky - The final hash size would be determined by whatever upper bound you used for the modular division in the second step.  For example, if you want your hashes to all be 5 digits long, then you could use `$smallnum = $bignum % 99999`.  This will work regardless of what is put into the initial MD5 or SHA1 hash.

Comment: @YuriKolovsky - Though naturally, using a smaller number will increase the risk of collisions in your hashes.  It's up to you to decide how important avoiding collisions is.

Comment: It should be added that md5/sha1 hashes are too long to fit in a php integer. You'll be already losing bytes when you call hexdec. In fact, I fear that for this reason taking the modulo will cause trouble.

Comment: Indeed, this makes the modulo return always 0, as the mantissa doesn't have enough digits to reach even the `10^5` digit. Sorry, -1 here.

Comment: @Artefacto - Wow, you're right, I hadn't thought of that.  I hadn't had a chance to test it out, but I'm surprised the OP didn't notice it either.  After some playing, I've found that if you take a substring of the first 16 characters of the hash string, it seems to fit back inside the integer's size limit.  Thanks for catching that.

Comment: With 16 hexadecimal characters, each one encoding 4 bits (2^4=16), this means 16 characters will encode 16*4 = 64 bits. PHP integers may only have 32-bits (e.g. on Windows) so that may also not work. I'll remove the downvote, though.

Comment: @Artefacto - I just tested it out with XAMPP on Windows 7, and everything seems to be ok.  If there are still problems, then taking a smaller substring wouldn't be hard; I just wanted to preserve as much of the hash as I could.

Comment: @derekerdmann It works better, but not exactly. It doesn't fit an integer, so PHP automatically uses a float instead. A float is implemented as a C `double`. The standard gives no guarantees as to the size of it (except its size >= the size of `float` and <= size of `long double`), but in practice they usually are IEEE 754 double-precision doubles, which store a 52-bit mantissa. So you're still losing 12 bits.

Comment: @derekerdmann Well, it's apparently more subtle than that because the modulus operator is not defined for double variables in C. I'd have to check the source for PHP for what it does in this case.

Comment: @Artefacto - Huh. I had no idea there was that much to it.  Probably doesn't matter that much for the OP anymore, but it's still an interesting problem.

Comment: what? does that mean that the generated number might not be unique?? I haven't implemented this yet, and assumed it made a numeric hash.
@Artefacto you can also have a go at answering the question :P

Comment: @YuriKolovsky Of course it won't be necessarily unique. The only question is how likely it will a collision will be. That said, if you need I think you should use `mt_rand` and if there's a collision, repeat.

Comment: `$bignum = hexdec( substr(sha1("test"), -15) );` is a better solution if you plan to use module as in `$bignum % $smallnum` later. This way it is consistent to sha1 without the cutting as we keep the end of the string for modulo.

Answer (score 20):

You can try `crc32()`. See the documentation at: http://php.net/manual/en/function.crc32.php

```
$checksum = crc32("The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.");
printf("%u\n", $checksum); // prints 2191738434
```

With that said, `crc` should **only** be used to `validate the integrity of data`.

Answer (score 8):

The problem of cut off the hash are the collisions, to avoid it try:

```
return  hexdec(crc32("Hello World"));
```

The `crc32()`:

> Generates the cyclic redundancy checksum polynomial of 32-bit lengths
>   of the str. This is usually used to validate the integrity of data
>   being transmitted.

That give us an integer of 32 bit, negative in 32 bits installation, or positive in the 64 bits. This integer could be store like an ID in a database. This don´t have collision problems, because it fits into 32bits variable, once you convert it to decimal with the `hexdec()` function.

Comment: Can you please explain how hashing a string does not have collisions in this case? To the best of my knowledge, all hashing has collisions.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, md5 is basically compromised, so you shouldn't be using it for anything but non-critical hashing.
PHP5 has the `hash()` function, see http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.hash.php.

Setting the last parameter to true will give you a string of binary data. Alternatively, you could split the resulting hexadecimal hash into pieces of 2 characters and convert them to integers individually, but I'd expect that to be much slower.

Comment: speed is not an issue, the only issue I have is that the num hash is unique not ridiculously long.

Answer (score 0):

Try [hashid](http://hashids.org/).
It hash a number into format you can define. The formats include how many character, and what character included.
Example:
$hashids->encode(1);
Will return "28630" depends on your format,

Answer (score 0):

Just use my manual hash method below:

Divide the number (e.g. 6 digit) by prime values, 3,5,7.

And get the first 6 values that are in the decimal places as the ID to be used. Do a check on uniqueness before actual creation of the ID, if a collision exists, increase the last digit by +1 until a non collision.
E.g. 123456 gives you 771428
123457 gives you 780952
123458 gives you 790476.