# Encrypting the value of an ID presented on a barcode being used for a ticketing system

Tags: php, mysql, security, encryption

I'm building a fairly simple ticketing system in PHP where when a user purchases a ticket, they're emailed a PDF with a barcode attached, the barcode contains their order ID, which when scanned at the event, matches the ID of the order in the database and validates the ticket.

However, I don't want the order id to presented in plain text in the barcode, as somebody could simply create a barcode with one digit higher or lower than their own and then have a valid ticket. I've looked at MD5 and some other encryption algorithms, but they produce 64 bit alphanumeric strings, which aren't ideal, as there is a possibility of the need to type the number in rather than scanning it.

Ideally, an id would convert from something like 123 to 864374357, so it's still fairly simple for a human to type.

Any ideas on what the best method of creating a simple encryption like this would be?

Comment: How are the tickets validated? It doesn't matter if the barcode is encrypted or not if they are not being checked. Assuming you'll use a barcode scanner to verify these, are you able to mark them as redeemed at the event, so the same codes cannot be used?

Comment: The tickets are scanned using a barcode scanner, which just reads the barcode and treats it as input in a html form, so when the first ticket is scanned it will read as "1" in the form field and submit. In this situation it would be simple for somebody to forge tickets and create barcodes of values 2,3,4,5 etc, knowing that the ids are incremental, and if they arrive first, their tickets will scan as valid, and the authentic tickets will be invalid.

Comment: Just generate a random number, instead of a sequential number. There is need for hashing here.

Comment: possible duplicate of [php: number only hash?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3379471/php-number-only-hash)

Comment: Hashing might be useful if you have an event for which connectivity is not available or fails unexpectedly. In this case, join your sequential number with a shared secret and hash it - you can then determine valid numbers locally without needing to be connected to your remote database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3379471/php-number-only-hash) here, I think it will give you what you need!

Basically, just take the MD5 (or any algorithm) hash and then run a little extra processing on it to convert it to a numeric format, or limit its length.

Comment: Yup, at a glance that looks like exactly what I was after. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could generate a short unique number which is then stored in a separate column in the database. You could write a function like:

```
function generate_random_number($length) {
    $random = '';

    for($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $random .= rand(0, 9);
    }

    return $random;
}
```

And generate a unique number:

```
do {
    $unique = generate_random_number(10);
    $sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM example_table WHERE unique_id = $unique";
    $res = $conn->query($sql);
} while($res->fetchColumn() > 0);

echo $unique;
```