# Generate 10 digit number from a string

Tags: php, string

Hi i have string like below

```
$string = "hello this is big test string"
```

or

```
$string = "hello small";
```

I need to generate unique 10 numbers from above strings.It don't have to be reversible , but the same unique 10 number should be generated always.

What i tried :

```
function toNumber($dest)
    {
        if ($dest)
            return ord(strtolower($dest)) - 96;
        else
            return 0;
    }


$str = "hello this is string";
$chars = str_split($str);
foreach($chars as $char){
echo toNumber($char) . " ";
}
```

P.s

1. for smaller string less than 10 char also should generate 10 random number
2. I have huge database of strings , so number should not be dependent on 1st or last 10 char..it should be mixture of all words and unique as possible.

Thanks all.

Comment: Duplicate from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3379471/php-number-only-hash

Comment: i added some more explanation to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

this is not possible since the english alphabet is consisting of 26 letters and numbers only got 10 "letters".
plus your string also might be longer than 10 chars.
so there is no way to create a unique number with just 10 digits for a string that's between 1 and n long.

for example, let's say your string is 10 characters long like the one in your example:

```
$string = "hello small";
```

then you take a simple translation method:

```
a = 0,  b = 1,  c = 2,  d = 3,  e = 4,  f = 5,  g = 6,  h = 7,  i = 8,  j = 9,  
k = 0,  l = 1,  m = 2,  n = 3,  o = 4,  p = 5,  q = 6,  r = 7,  s = 8,  t = 9,  
u = 0,  v = 1,  w = 2,  x = 3,  y = 4,  z = 5, [space] = 6
```

then the string translation would be:

```
74114682011
```

if you got another string, which could be some name...

```
$string = "robby imull";
```

.. it would translate into the exact same digit-code.

*(i know this is a strange name but i just did some fast example)*

i hope you get what's the problem with your idea of limiting the code to 10 digits.

Comment: Are you saying that SHA1 and md5 are just doing the impossible then? Collisions may occur but are very rare. With what he is asking, they would occur even more frequently, but that ain't just plain impossible...

Comment: @Salketer since when is sha1 or md5 limited to 10 digits ?

Comment: That's why I say there would be more collisions, but the chances would be fairly low if he don't have trillions of entries...

Comment: @Salketer well, if you generate something like an unique id for the strings then chances are fairly low - but if you wanna generate the digits based on the characters, chances are high.

Answer (score 0):

make a substr function on an md5 of your string:

```
substr(hexdec(md5($string)), 0, 10)
```

Comment: its coming with some decimal and i also would like the increase the count later

Answer (score 0):

This will do

```
$input = "hello worlds";

$encrypted = encryptIt( $input );

function encryptIt( $q ) {
    $cryptKey  = 'qJB0rGtIn5UB1xG03efyCp';
    $qEncoded      = base64_encode( mcrypt_encrypt( MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, md5( $cryptKey ), $q, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, md5( md5( $cryptKey ) ) ) );
    return( $qEncoded );
}
echo substr($encrypted, -20, 10);
```

Comment: This will always return a 10 digit same string for the same input and you can increase the counter anytime by changing the value 10 in substr. Hope it helps !!