# how to create a row of digits based on a string in php

Tags: php, cryptography

I know how MD5 or sha1 functions work. But I need something that works similar but instead of creating some hash from input, function must create only a row of digits based on a letter or others symbols in input.

**For instance:**

> Input: abcdefgsdadasd
>
> Output: 420393421425 (a number of digits is set by option)
>
> Input: b
>
> Output: 550005500550

Is there any solutions out of the box? Or this case requires special algorithm based on some alphabet.

Comment: Something like the Caesar cipher?  http://pl1.php.net/manual/en/function.str-rot13.php

Comment: @Progrock I would say something like sha1 function, which returns a static length of hash but only with digits in it.

Comment: If it's a hash you want?
  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3379471/php-number-only-hash

Comment: @Progrock Yeah, this is what I need. Thanks! You may post this like answer, thus I can mark the correct answer.

Comment: If there is an exact answer to the question then your question is likely to be marked as dupe instead of answers, Medion. Please *try* and look for dupes first (yeah, I know, sometimes they can be hard to find - no harm done). Welcome to StackOverflow by the way.